# How to use metaWeblog.newPost (xmlrpc api) to schedule a new post?

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

I'm trying to create a new post on my site remotely using  XMLRPC API and I'm using metaWeblog.newPost function as per codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_MetaWeblog_API

I have successfully created new posts into WordPress but when it comes to scheduling I fail.

```
$content['title'] = $title;
$content['excerpt'] = $post_content;
$content['categories'] = array($response[1]['categoryName']);
$content['description'] = $post_content;
$content['mt_keywords'] = $post_tags;

if (!$client->query('metaWeblog.newPost','', $admin, $pass, $content, true)) {
        echo "Post created!";
}
```

How can i schedule a post? I don't see any schedule date in codex. What date parameter should i add? Thanks